# Magento 2: How to create custom email template for a specific form?

Tags: email-templates, magento-2.1.3

I created a custom form and even extended the controller of Magento Contact Us and modified it. Now my problem is that whenever, I fill out the form that I created, It will use the email template of Magento Contact Us to send notification. Sorry I'm just new to this. I hope you can help me.

And also I have created a custom email template for my form under Marketing>Email Templates, I want this email template to be used in my custom form.

Attached is the current screenshot of my Index.php Controller.

[image]

Here is the code of Index.php Controller

```
    <?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Company\ModuleName\Controller;

use Magento\Framework\Exception\NotFoundException;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;

/**
 * Contact index controller
 */
abstract class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * Recipient email config path
     */
    const XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT = 'contact/email/recipient_email';

    /**
     * Sender email config path
     */
    const XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER = 'contact/email/sender_email_identity';

    /**
     * Email template config path
     */
    const XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE = 'contact/email/email_template';

    /**
     * Enabled config path
     */
    const XML_PATH_ENABLED = 'contact/contact/enabled';

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder
     */
    protected $_transportBuilder;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface
     */
    protected $inlineTranslation;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    protected $scopeConfig;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storeManager;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
        \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        $this->inlineTranslation = $inlineTranslation;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    /**
     * Dispatch request
     *
     * @param RequestInterface $request
     * @return \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NotFoundException
     */
    public function dispatch(RequestInterface $request)
    {
        if (!$this->scopeConfig->isSetFlag(self::XML_PATH_ENABLED, ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE)) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Page not found.'));
        }
        return parent::dispatch($request);
    }
}
```

And Here is the Controller

```
    <?php
/**
 *
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Company\ModuleName\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

class Cs extends  \Company\ModuleName\Controller\Index
{
    /**
     * @var DataPersistorInterface
     */
    private $dataPersistor;

    /**
     * Post user question
     *
     * @return void
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        if (!$post) {
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
        }

        $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();
        try {
            $postObject = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
            $postObject->setData($post);

            $error = false;

            if (!\Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['name']), 'NotEmpty')) {
                $error = true;
            }
            if (!\Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['address']), 'NotEmpty')) {
                $error = true;
            }
            if (!\Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['mix-name']), 'NotEmpty')) {
                $error = true;
            }
            if (!\Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['company']), 'NotEmpty')) {
                $error = true;
            }
            if (!\Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['city']), 'NotEmpty')) {
                $error = true;
            }
            if (!\Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['address']), 'NotEmpty')) {
                $error = true;
            }
            if (!\Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['email']), 'EmailAddress')) {
                $error = true;
            }
             if (!\Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['telephone']), 'NotEmpty')) {
                $error = true;
            }
             if (!\Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['zip']), 'NotEmpty')) {
                $error = true;
            }
             if (!\Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['fax']), 'NotEmpty')) {
                $error = true;
            }
             if (!\Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['concentration']), 'NotEmpty')) {
                $error = true;
            }
             if (!\Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['instructions']), 'NotEmpty')) {
                $error = true;
            }
            // if (\Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['hideit']), 'NotEmpty')) {
            //     $error = true;
            // }
            if ($error) {
                throw new \Exception();
            }
            $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
            $transport = $this->_transportBuilder
                ->setTemplateIdentifier($this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, $storeScope))
                ->setTemplateOptions(
                    [
                        'area' => \Magento\Backend\App\Area\FrontNameResolver::AREA_CODE,
                        'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID,
                    ]
                )
                ->setTemplateVars(['customer' => $postObject])
                ->setFrom($this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER, $storeScope))
                ->addTo($this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT, $storeScope))
                ->setReplyTo($post['email'])
                ->getTransport();

            $transport->sendMessage();
            $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(
                __('Thanks for contacting us with your comments and questions. We\'ll respond to you very soon.')
            );
            $this->getDataPersistor()->clear('contact_us');
            $this->_redirect('thank-you-contact-us');
            return;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
            $this->messageManager->addError(
                __('We can\'t process your request right now. Sorry, that\'s all we know.')
                // __($e->getMessage())
            );
            $this->getDataPersistor()->set('analytical-instrument-supplies-standards-custom-standards.html', $post);
            $this->_redirect('analytical-instrument-supplies-standards-custom-standards.html');
            return;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get Data Persistor
     *
     * @return DataPersistorInterface
     */
    private function getDataPersistor()
    {
        if ($this->dataPersistor === null) {
            $this->dataPersistor = ObjectManager::getInstance()
                ->get(DataPersistorInterface::class);
        }

        return $this->dataPersistor;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share your full code which you have tried yet.

Comment: Hi Rakesh, Ok I will post it in here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**app/code/Company/ModuleName/etc/adminhtml/system.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
        <system>
            <tab id="customformtab" translate="label" sortOrder="1">
                <label>Voucher</label>
            </tab>
            <section id="customform" showInDefault="1" showInStore="1" showInWebsite="1" translate="label" type="text">
                <label>Custom form</label>
                <tab>customformtab</tab>
                <resource>Company_ModuleName::company</resource>
                <group id="general" showInDefault="1" showInStore="1" showInWebsite="1" sortOrder="1" type="text">
                    <label>Contact form Settings</label>   
                   <field id="customer_email_sender" showInDefault="1" showInStore="1" showInWebsite="1" sortOrder="1" translate="label" type="select">
                        <label>Email Sender</label>
                        <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Email\Identity</source_model>
                    </field>  
                </group>
            </section>
        </system>
</config>
```

**app/code/Company/ModuleName/etc/email_templates.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Email:etc/email_templates.xsd">
    <template area="frontend" file="customform.html" id="customform_general_customer_email_sender" label="Customform" module="Company_ModuleName" type="html"/>
</config>
```

**app/code/Company/ModuleName/view/frontend/email/customform.html**

```
<!--@subject Custom form {{var store.getFrontendName()}} @-->

{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}
Custom code of your template
{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```

Change,

```
`const XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE = 'customform/general/customer_email_sender';
```

Comment: Hi Rakesh, Thanks man! I've been waiting for your answer! I will test this out also. I'll update you once this will work in my end. Thanks again

Comment: Thanks! This worked in my end. but I added few modifications. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is that difficult. If you have seperate form and works differently you don't need to extend the contact module controller.

There are few steps to follow:

1. On your module you need to create "email_templates.xml" file.
2. Create the template for the email
3. And on your controller you need the instance of

**Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder,
Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface**

Please follow https://webkul.com/blog/magento2-create-custom-email-templates/ this tutorial for detail codes and explanation.

I have created a simple working module following this.

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Hi Anton, I have created an email template in the backend of the site in Marketing>Email Templates, I want to use that template if someone will fill out my custom form and submit it.

Comment: You cannot create email template from admin, you can just extends existing email templates. If you have a requirement of managing separate type of email template you can just create new email template in module and it will be visible on admin on Marketing>Email Templates section too. Have you checked the link i have added on the answer?

Comment: Ok thank you for your answer aton. I will test this out. I'll update you once it will work in my end. Thanks

Comment: sure if it helps, please don't forget to accept and vote the answer

Comment: Ok aton sure no problem. I may have some questions to you are you online all day? If you don't mind. Thanks

Comment: Yes sure send it through. I will be glad if i can help\

Comment: Ok Aton Thanks again. I will test both of the answers in my question, I will update you also once this works in my end.