# Magento 2 - How to include custom e-mail template?

Tags: magento2, email, transactional-mail

I added a custom .html email template at **THEME\Magento_Email\email\usp_block.html** (i also tried *THEME\Magento_Email\view\frontend\email\usp_block.html*).

Then I added the file **THEME/etc/email_templates.xml** with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Email:etc/email_templates.xsd">
    <template id="design_email_usp_block_template" label="USP Block" file="usp_block.html" type="html" module="Magento_Email" area="frontend"/>
</config>
```

Now I added a new template in the Magento Backend at **Marketing -> E-Mail Templates** and tried to include my template like this:

```
{{template config_path="design/email/usp_block_template"}}
```

Then I flushed the cache. But if I preview, then I get this:

> Error while filtering the template: The email template
> 'design_email_usp_block_template' is not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The User aligent-skumar on GitHub provided the [answer](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/32480):

> MODULE = app/code/NameSpace/ModuleName

1. Create your template:

**MODULE\view\frontend\templates\usp.phtml**

```
<div>This is a test</div>
```

2. declare template in email_template.xml:

**MODULE/etc/email_templates.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Email:etc/email_templates.xsd">
    <template id="custom_email_usp_template" label="USP Block" file="usp.html" type="html" module="Magento_Email" area="frontend"/>
</config>
```

3. Create layout file:

**MODULE/view/frontend/layout/custom_email_usp_template.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd"
      label="Subscription renew notification email items" design_abstraction="custom">
    <block name="test.email.viewmodel" class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="NameSpace_ModuleName::usp.phtml">
    
    <!-- OPTIONAL:
        <arguments>
            <argument name="view_model" xsi:type="object">NameSpace\ModuleName\ViewModel\<ViewModelClass></argument>
        </arguments>
    -->
    </block>
</page>
```

4. Define E-Mail template definieren
   MODULE\view\frontend\email\usp.html

```
 {{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}
     {{layout handle="custom_email_usp_template" area="frontend"}}  <-- now you can include your template like this
 {{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```

5. Now you can use your template in the backend:

**Marketing -> Communication: E-Mail Templates -> Create new template.**

You will find this in the dropdown now:

```
Magento E-Mail:
     USP-Block
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that what you are trying to do is something similar to how the header and footer blocks are inserted inside email templates. However, for these 2 blocks have their path defined as a system configuration path, it's not a naming convention (see `vendor/magento/module-email/etc/di.xml` [image]

In `vendor/magento/framework/Filter/Template.php` you have [image]

So what I get from this is that if you want to include your custom block the same way that the email header&footer are, **as global blocks**, then it means that you also have to define it the same way, by declaring the config path where this template is registered and saving the values, given the instruction `<PATH> equals the XPATH to the system configuration value that contains the value of the template.` Which means that you need a custom module for creating this new global block.

---

But I am not sure you actually need it to be a global block, you could add a simple email template and load it in admin (select template from dropdown and click button 'load template').

Check this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/179107/35330 that can help you. Worth to mention that the 'module' property inside `email_templates.xml` should point to your custom module, not Magento_Email, or otherwise it will try to look for it inside Magento_Email module and once again, not find it.

Comment: Thank you, loading it from the dropdown ist not an option for me. I want to insert a include statement into various templates, just like the header and footer are getting loaded. I try to figure out how I can copy the behaviour from header and footer so I can just insert my template anywhere, it is no where documented.

Comment: roger that. i recommend you check the magento `module-email` module and debug how they did it there. i also had to piece together some bits from that module in my answer above.

Comment: No way, I can't figure out how to copy the behaviour from header&footer. I tried it and also added an entry to core_config_data (manually by hand), the template was finally loaded now, but if I go to Content-> Design: Configuration and Edit my Theme, then I get `The "componentType" configuration parameter is required for the "email_usp_template" component.
`

Comment: yeah, i thought this wasn't easy.. sorry to hear this. have you also considered using a variable instead? https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/marketing/variables-custom.html

Comment: Variables are not working in this case, since template code like `<img src="{{config path='web/secure/base_url'}}media/wysiwyg/xy.png">` is not getting interpreted. It just gets printed raw. But thanks for your help so far, maybe someday I will find the solution.

Comment: no problem, wish i was more useful :)

Comment: @Black can you please create a system configuration for "design/email/usp_block_template", no need to fetch it's value just create it and check if it works.